# Ambiguous redirect in a Unix Shell Script with if-elif-else statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, logic

I've just begun writing if-else statements in Unix. This is a short Bash script I recently wrote. I keep getting an ambiguous redirect error, however I can't figure out the problem.

When executed, I get the following error message:

```
stringComp: line 17: $str2: ambiguous redirect
stringComp: line 20: $str2: ambiguous redirect
stringComp: line 23: [: too many arguments
```

Here is the script:

```
str1="I like turtles"
str2="I want to be Iron Man"

if [ $str1 > $str2 ]
then
        echo "The first string is longer than the second"
elif [ $str1 < $str2 ]
then
        echo "The second string is longer than the first"
elif [ $str1 = $str2 ]
then
        echo "Both strings are of equal length"
else
        echo "Invalid argument"
fi
```

Any advice on what to do here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$str1 > $str2` is not comparing string length, `>` is actually redirection operator when used with `[` which is a separate program in Unix systems.

You can just use `${#str1}` to get the string length:

```
str1="I like turtles"
str2="I want to be Iron Man"

if [[ ${#str1} -gt ${#str2} ]]
then
        echo "The first string is longer than the second"
elif [[ ${#str1} -lt ${#str2} ]]
then
        echo "The second string is longer than the first"
elif [[ ${#str1} -eq ${#str2} ]]
then
        echo "Both strings are of equal length"
else
        echo "Invalid argument"
fi
```

Also better to use `[[...]]` in bash.

Comment: Can also use -gt,-lt,-eq etc.

Comment: @sudheeshshetty Actually, you *must* use `-gt` and `-lt`, or else it does string comparison rather than numeric comparison. The difference is that e.g. `[[ 10 > 9 ]]` is false, because "1" comes before "9" in sorting order; but `[[ 10 -gt 9 ]]` is true. Or you can use a numeric expression like `(( 10 > 9 ))`.

Comment: So here we might have to use -gt, -lt and -eq then.